# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentElement') during Unit Test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test for the following function:

```
    focusSkipButton(event: MouseEvent, isLoggedIn: boolean): void {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return;
    }
    const button: HTMLButtonElement = document.querySelector('.skip-btn');
    const overlay = document.querySelector('.story-viewer-login-container');
    const target = event.target as Element;
    if (event.target !== overlay &&
      (target.parentElement && target.parentElement !== overlay)) {
      button.focus();
    } 
   }
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
it('should set focus on skip buuton', fakeAsync(()=>{
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    spyOn(document, 'querySelector').and.returnValue(button);
    spyOn(button, 'focus');

    var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
    });

    let parent = document.createElement('div');
    let child = document.createElement('div');
    parent.append(child);
    child.dispatchEvent(event);

    component.focusSkipButton(event, false);
    tick();

    expect(button.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();

    component.focusSkipButton(event, true);
    tick();

    expect(button.focus).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

However during running this test I am getting an error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentElement')
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The element you dispatched the click event on isn't in the DOM. `target` property on `MouseEvent` is null in that case.

You could try adding the element to the DOM, but generally I would avoid doing DOM access within Angular without `ViewChild` and the other Angular ways of doing it.